# SDCC compiler switch statement, what is ack: section for?

Tags: c, switch-statement, sdcc

I saw the following code in CCTL (~line 330) https://github.com/jobytaffey/cctl/blob/master/cctl/main.c

```
switch(page)
{
   // ...
   ack:
      cons_putc(0);
}
```

What is the `ack:` section for?  It looks like same as `default:` to me.  I can't find it in the SDCC docs either.

Is this something in C spec?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a C keyword; it's just a label.  Note the corresponding `goto` statements.

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at that code for a few hours and just could not see the goto.